# GPU driver version error on google virtual machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nvidia, google-cloud-compute-engine

I got an error Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch on a cloud virtual machine for unknown reasons, the system was working normally then suddenly crashed and reported such an error,  [image]

I'm very confused and don't know what is the cause, can someone with experience in this matter please help me, I want to know why I get such an error and is there any way to prevent it, thanks

Comment: 1. Stackoverflow is more intended for programming questions rather than configuration/installation of drivers so the question is off-topic. You may have more luck in [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). 2. Nothing can be read from the image; never upload errors as images but as plain text

Answer (score 2):

As per this [doc](https://kb.brightcomputing.com/knowledge-base/how-can-i-fix-failed-to-initialize-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch/) curated by Bright computing knowledge base the “Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch?” error generally means the CUDA Driver is still running an older release that is incompatible with the CUDA toolkit version currently in use.

> Rebooting the VM is the easiest way to fix the issue. Rebooting the VM
> will ensure that the drivers are properly initialized after the
> upgrade.
>
> If you do not wish to reboot the VM, you will need to remove the
> existing Nvidia kernel module and load the new module.
>
> **On the VM**:
>
> Remove the existing Nvidia kernel module:
>
> ```
> modprobe -r nvidia nvidia_uvm
> ```
>
> Reload the systemd units:
>
> ```
> systemctl daemon-reload
> ```
>
> Build and load the new kernel module:
>
> ```
> systemctl restart cuda-driver
> ```
>
> If the old Nvidia Kernel module is still loading, you may need to
> delete the module from the software image and node. You can check this
> with:
>
> ```
> find /lib/modules | grep nvidia
> find /cm/images/default-image/lib/modules | grep nvidia
> ```

Refer to this official [document](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#handle-uninstallation) to get rid of all previous CUDA and NVIDIA driver files, follow the steps in the cuda linux installation guide and then reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I managed to fix it this way. However, I don't know why I have that problem, the virtual machine is working properly, I also did not update the driver version, but it still gives me the error, I don't know why, is it due to automatic mechanism some update?